# Varchar2 to date in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Can somebody help me with how to convert varchar column into Date data type?

My createDate column has VarChar2 data type in format example 20050923
I would like to convert this column into format example 2005/09/23

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD (new_create_date DATE);
UPDATE test SET new_create_date=TO_DATE(createDate,'MM/DD/YYYY');
```

When I run these sql I get format 23-aug-2005. Why?

Comment: You can't store `DATE` datatypes in a `VARCHAR2` column. You need to change the datatype of the column to accept `DATE` values and set the format.

Comment: your createDate column doesn't have same format you use in to_Date (MM/DD/YYYY). you have to write exact format of you column value. i think it is YYYYMMDD

Answer (score 1):

Internally date is stored as a 7 byte value.   Formatting is not something that is stored there.  You get formatting when you pull the data out of the table.

Try this.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(NEW_CREATE_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY')
FROM TEST
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
update test
    set new_create_date to_date(createDate, 'YYYYMMDD');
```

You just need to give `to_date()` the right format string.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your database NLS_DATE_FORMAT must be in DD-MON-YYYY format, you can check that by using the below mentioned query.

SELECT *
FROM   nls_session_parameters
WHERE  parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';

Also by definition to_date(x,format) converts a string i.e. x to a datetime, the format part is an optional part which indicates the format that is present for the string value x.

You can further use to_char(x,format) function in your case which converts the x datetime to a string as mentioned by the EvilTech.